# Composer won't use my fork

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php

I'm trying to get composer to use my own fork of a library.

Original: https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api
My Fork: https://github.com/TransitScreen/php-github-api

I was able to install the original with composer simply by adding this to composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "knplabs/github-api": "~1.4"
    }
}
```

I followed [the instructions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs) in the documentation, and changed it to this:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/TransitScreen/php-github-api.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "knplabs/github-api": "dev-master"
    },
    "minimum-stabilitiy": "dev"
}
```

In my forked repository I have both a `master` and `dev-master` branch created. It's not clear to me which is correct, so I made both. I've also tried by using `"type" : "vcs"` and removing the `.git` from the URL. Neither one works. I run `composer update` and then the `composer.lock` file still points to the original repo URL, not mine. So I never get my changes when I run `composer install`.

What am I doing wrong??

PS: I've noticed that the library I'm trying to fork has this in it's composer.json file:

```
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "1.4.x-dev"
    }
}
```

I haven't found any documentation to explain what effect the alias might have. For example, should my forked repository have a `1.4.x` branch??

**Update 1**
By the way, I know some of my configurations must be correct because I when run `composer update` after deleting the cache, there is a moment when I see that it's reading the composer.json of my (the correct) repository. But then afterwards composer.lock still points to the original (incorrect).

**Update 2**
I've also tried using `composer update --prefer-source` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the problem!

I had edited the `composer.json` file inside my forked repository... It looked like this:

```
{
    "name": "knplabs/github-api",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "GitHub API v3 client",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/TransitScreen/php-github-api",
    "keywords": ["github", "gh", "api", "gist"],
    "license": "MIT",
```

But I changed it to this:

```
{
    "name": "transitscreen/php-github-api",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "GitHub API v3 client",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/TransitScreen/php-github-api",
    "keywords": ["github", "gh", "api", "gist"],
    "license": "MIT",
```

I thought that the name needed to match the new repository, but I was wrong. When I changed it back to the original name, everything works!

Many thanks to @Tomas for offering useful troubleshooting tips.

I didn't see any documentation about this anywhere, so I PRed an update to the composer docs: https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/4329

Answer (score 1):

First, try to rename your fork branch to something else (best unique and not available in the origin) and use that.

To be specific: https://github.com/TransitScreen/gh-api/tree/dev-master

`dev-master` => `my-feature`

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/TransitScreen/php-github-api"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "knplabs/github-api": "newsearch"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: See my most recent **Update 1**

Comment: Now I get an error: `  Problem 1
    - The requested package knplabs/github-api dev-newsearch could not be found.
`. I created a `newsearch` branch in my forked repo and changed the require to: `"knplabs/github-api": "dev-newsearch"`. I also renamed my forked repository to match the original name

Comment: There is no `dev-newsearch`, I see only `newsearch`. https://github.com/TransitScreen/php-github-api/tree/newsearch What about that?

Comment: I thought the documentation wanted me to add `dev-` to the branch name: `Your custom branch name must be prefixed with "dev-"` Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: First: Have you tried? I use it like I wrote with no problems.

Comment: Yes. If I remove the `dev-` then I get this error:   `[UnexpectedValueException]                                                   
  Could not parse version constraint newsearch: Invalid version string "newsearch"`

Comment: I just updated your answer with the exact code that I'm using.